# shell script inside python script with argument as sql script

Tags: python, sql, shell

Python script:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['sh ' + '/dir_path/script_to_Call_sql_script.sh ' + '\"select ID,DATE,STATUS from XYZ_TABLE;\"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
BOOK=out.split()
```

The above scripts NOT work for giving output. But script pulling default script select.sql from same directory.

If I deleted the select.sql query then it gives below error:

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file "select.sql"
```

I want to pass differents ( total 6) SQL script to this code one by one.
for example:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sh ' + '/dir_path/script_to_Call_sql_script.sh ' + ' first.sql'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Why are you specifying `sh` *and* `shell=True`?  It could be that the quotes are being stripped by calling the shell from the shell.  If the script has execute access and a `#!` line then you should not need `sh` or `shell=True`.

Comment: instead of `./dir_path/script_to_Call_sql_script.sh` I am using `sh` ... Even after removing I am getting the same error.  Script looks for select.sql file only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code resolved my issue. I use os.popen instead of subprocess.Popen

```
os.popen('./dir_path/script_to_Call_sql_script.sh sql_query.sql').read()
```

Thanks guys :-)